# Why git blame does not follow renames?

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

```
$ pwd
/data/mdi2/classes

$ git blame -L22,+1 -- utils.js
99b7a802 mdi2/utils.js (user 2015-03-26 21:54:57 +0200 22)  #comment

$ git blame -L22,+1 99b7a802^ -- utils.js
fatal: no such path mdi2/classes/utils.js in 99b7a802^
```

As you have noticed, the file were in different directory in that commit

```
$ git blame -L22,+1 99b7a802^ -- ../utils.js
c5105267 (user 2007-04-10 08:00:20 +0000 22)    #comment 2
```

Despite on doc

```
The origin of lines is automatically followed across whole-file renames (currently there is no option to turn
       the rename-following off)
```

blame does not follow renames. Why?

**UPDATE:** Short answer

`git blame` follow renames but not for `git blame COMMIT^ -- <filename>`

But this is too hard to track file renames manually through bulk of renames and ton of history.
I think, this behaviour must be fixed to silently follow renames for `git blame COMMIT^ -- <filename>`. Or, at least, `--follow` must be implemented, so I can: `git blame --follow COMMIT^ -- <filename>`

**UPDATE2:** That is impossible. Read below.

**ANSWER FROM MAILLIST** by Junio C Hamano

> `git blame` follow renames but not for `git blame COMMIT^ -- <filename>`

Suppose you have file A and file B in your version v1.0.

Six month down the road, the code was much refactored, and you do
not need the contents of these two files separately.  You have
removed A and B and much of what they had is now in file C.  That is
the current state.

```
git blame -C HEAD -- C
```

may follow the contents from both just fine, but if you *were*
allowed to say

```
git blame v1.0 -- C
```

what does it even mean?  C did not exist v1.0 at all.  Are you
asking to follow the contents of A back then, or B?  How did you
tell you meant A and not B when you told it C in this command?

"git blame" follows content movements, and never treats "renames" in
any special way, as it is a stupid thing to do to think a rename is
somehow special ;-)

The way you tell what content to start digging from to the command
from its command line is to give starting point commit (defaults to
HEAD but you may give COMMIT^ as your example) and the path in that
starting point.  As it does not make any sense to tell C to Git and
then magically make it guess you meant A in some cases and B in some
other.  If v1.0 did not have C, the only sensible thing to do is to
exit instead of making a guess (and without telling the user how it
guessed).

Comment: Note: This is an esoteric question specifically about `COMMIT^`. For basic use, Git blame works seamlessly across renames. No extra options required.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`git blame` *does* follow renames (as does `git log` if you give it `--follow`).  The problem lies in the *way* it follows renames, which is a not-very-thorough hack: as it steps back one commit at a time (from each child to each parent), it makes a diff—the same kind of diff you can make manually with:

```
git diff -M SHA1^ SHA1
```

—and checks to see if this diff detected a rename.<sup>1</sup>

That's all fine as far as it goes, but it means that for `git blame` to detect a rename, (a) `git diff -M` has to be *able* to detect it (fortunately that is the case here) and—here's what's causing you problems—it must *step across the rename*.

For instance, suppose the commit graph looks a bit like this:

```
A <-- B <-- ... Q <-- R <-- S <-- T
```

where each uppercase letter represents a commit.  Suppose further that a file was renamed in commit `R`, so that in commits `R` through `T` it has name `newname` while in commits `A` through `Q` it has name `oldname`.

If you run `git blame -- newname`, the sequence starts at `T`, compares `S` and `T`, compares `R` and `S`, and compares `Q` and `R`.  *When* it compares `Q` and `R`, `git blame` discovers the name-change, and starts looking for `oldname` in commits `Q` and earlier, so when it compares `P` and `Q` it compares files `oldname` and `oldname` in those two commits.

If, on the other hand, you run `git blame R^ -- newname` (or `git blame Q -- newname`) so that the sequence starts at commit `Q`, there is no file `newname` in that commit, and there is no rename when comparing `P` and `Q`, and `git blame` simply gives up.

The trick is that if you're starting from a commit in which the file had the previous name, you must give git the old name:

```
git blame R^ -- oldname
```

and then it all works again.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the [`git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), you will see that there is a `-M` option that controls *how* `git diff` detects renames.  The `blame` code modifies this a bit (and in fact does two passes, one with `-M` turned off and a second with `-M` turned on) and uses its own (different) `-M` option for somewhat different purposes, but ultimately it's using this same code.

---

[**Edit** to add reply to comment (didn't fit as a comment itself)]:

> Is any tool that can show me file renames like: git renames <filename> SHA date oldname->newname

Not exactly, but `git diff -M` comes close, and may be close enough.

I'm not sure what you mean by "SHA date" here, but `git diff -M` allows you to supply two SHA-1s and compares left-vs-right.  Add `--name-status` to get just file names and dispositions.  Hence `git diff -M --name-status HEAD oldsha1` *may* report that to convert from `HEAD` to `oldsha1`, git believes you should `R`ename a file and will report the old name as the "new" name.  For instance, in the git repository itself, there is a file currently named `Documentation/giteveryday.txt` that used to have a slightly different name:

```
$ git diff -M --name-status HEAD 992cb206
M       .gitignore
M       .mailmap
[...snip...]
M       Documentation/diff-options.txt
R097    Documentation/giteveryday.txt   Documentation/everyday.txt
D       Documentation/everyday.txto
[...]
```

If that's the file you care about, you're good.  The two problems here are:

- finding an SHA1: where did `992cb206` come from?  If you already have an SHA-1, that's easy; if not, `git rev-list` is the SHA1-finding tool; read its documentation;
- and the fact that following a series of renames through each commit one commit at a time, as `git blame` does, may produce quite different answers than comparing a much-later commit (`HEAD`) against a much-earlier commit (`992cb206` or whatever).  In this case, it comes out the same, but the "similarity index" here is 97 out of 100.  If it were to have been modified much more in some of the intermediate steps, that similarity index might fall below 50% ... yet, if we were to compare a revision just a *little* after `992cb206` to `992cb206` (as `git blame` would), perhaps the similarity index between those two files might be higher.

What's needed (and missing) is for `git rev-list` itself to implement `--follow`, so that all commands that use `git rev-list` internally—i.e., most commands that work on more than just one revision—can do the trick.  Along the way, it would be nice if it worked in the other direction (currently `--follow` is newer-to-older only, i.e., works fine with `git blame` and works ok with `git log` as long you don't ask for oldest history first with `--reverse`).

Comment: Is any tool that can show me file renames like: `git renames <filename>` SHA date oldname->newname

Comment: See added edit; note also that `git blame` itself shows you the updated file name.

Comment: with that command I try to get answer what is DATE and what is SHA-1 when <filename> was renamed. So I can take oldname and sha1 to put these as blame arguments. But if --follow will be implemented as you suggest I do not require this command at all

Answer (score 3):

**see UPDATE**. Now you can follow renamed files.

Latest git has interesting command. Add next to your config:

```
[alias]
    follow= "!sh -c 'git log --topo-order -u -L $2,${3:-$2}:"$1"'" -
```

Now you can:

```
$git follow <filename> <linefrom> [<lineto>]
```

And you will see each commit that change specified lines in `<filename>`.

Also you can be interested in `--follow` option of `git log` command:

> Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file).

If you are interested in copy detection use [`-C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Cltngt):

> Detect copies as well as renames. See also --find-copies-harder. If n is specified, it has the same meaning as for -M.

`-C` will look different files in same commit. If you want detect that code was taken from different file that was not changed in this commit. Then you should provide [`--find-copies-harder`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---find-copies-harder) option.

> For performance reasons, by default, -C option finds copies only if the original file of the copy was modified in the same changeset. This flag makes the command inspect unmodified files as candidates for the source of copy. This is a very expensive operation for large projects, so use it with caution. Giving more than one -C option has the same effect.

**UPDATE**
I improved this alias:

```
[alias]
follow = "!bash -c '                                                 \
    if [[ $1 == \"/\"* ]]; then                                      \
        FILE=$1;                                                     \
    else                                                             \
        FILE=${GIT_PREFIX}$1;                                        \
    fi;                                                              \
    echo \"git log --topo-order -u -L $2,${3:-$2}:\\\"$FILE\\\" $4 \";   \
    git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --topo-order -u -L $2,${3:-$2}:\"$FILE\" $4;\
' --"
```

> For reference, here's what the bits of this alias are:
>
> - [git alias](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a80be152923a46f04a06bade7bcc72870e46ca09/Documentation/config/alias.txt#L27-L28)
>
>   > `GIT_PREFIX` is set as returned by running `git rev-parse --show-prefix` from the original current directory.
> - [`--topo-order`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---topo-order) will order commits by development tracks, instead of ordering by their date and possibly mixing two different tracks.
> - [`-u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--u) is the same as `-p`, `--patch`, so this will generate a patch
> - [`-L`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt) the line range
> - [`-w`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--w), same as `--ignore-all-space`, ignores whitespace differences
> - [`-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--b) ignores space changes.
> - [`-p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--p), generates a patch same as `-u`, `--patch`
> - [`--ignore-blank-lines`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ignore-blank-lines)

Now you can track how specified range of lines are changed:

```
git follow file_name.c 30 35
```

Even you can continue follow different file starting with commit (@arg4)

```
git follow old_file_name.c 30 35 85ce061
```

85ce061 - is commit where file was renamed

NOTICE: Unfortunately git does not take into account changes in working directory. Thus if you do local changes to file you must stash it before you can `follow` changes